# Гарантированный способ проверки что строка прогонялась через urlencode

Tags: php

Как гарантированно проверить что строка прошла через `urlencode` и строку надо прогнать через `urldecode` прежде чем с ней работать?

Comment: Никак . . . . .

Comment: А в чем проблема прогонять ее через urldecode без всяких проверок?

Comment: Это побратим вопроса "Как гарантировано проверить, что файл - текстовый".

Comment: @newman в том, что если я напишу `a%20b`, я могу иметь в виду именно с процентом `a%20b`, а нифига не с пробелом `a b`

Comment: @andreymal У меня немного в другом. У меня строка кодируется многократно, если я отправляю данные формы не один раз. Может в моем случае поможет что то типа `urldecode(urlencode('строка'))`

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь это означает, что вы плохо организовали свой код и сами же в нём запутались. Переписывайте его так, чтобы для любой строки можно было абсолютно точно сказать, где как она преобразовывалась, просто прочитав код в редакторе вообще без его запуска

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите проверять вообще любую произвольную строку. То скорее всего не получится.  ИМХО вы ищите проблему не в том месте, скорее всего трабла архитектурная и вам следует сделать так, что бы в urlencode передавалась строка один раз или сохранять не измененную строку.

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте на наличие знака **`=`** в строке, в кодированной он будет иметь вид **`%3`**:

```
$param1 = "beyong";
$param2 = "galvanize";

$qs = urlencode("param1=$param1&param2=$param2");

if( preg_match("/%3D/", $qs) ) {
    echo "query string is already urlencoded";
}
```

Comment: Что если исходная строка это и есть `%3` и она на самом деле не прогонялась?

Comment: я так думаю, что если urldecode по назначению использовать, то строка в любом случае будет иметь хотя бы одну пару ключ=значение

Comment: Исходя из того, что данный вопрос вообще был задан, я уверен, что urlencode используется автором не совсем по назначению :)

Comment: согласен, но самому стало интересно )

Comment: И, кстати, всё-таки не `%3`, а `%3D`

Comment: @andreymal дадада, спасибо